# How to round a float up on 5

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, rounding

So I was surprised I didn't find anything regarding this.

I have a python script which is testing a C++ program. It needs to format a float in the same way `std::setprecision` does. That is a float like 1.265 should be rounded UP to 1.27 (2 dp).

Now I have the following code:
`"{:.2f}".format(myFloat)`

The issue is that numbers like 1.265 are rounded to 1.26 and my tests fail. `setprecision` rounds 1.265 to 1.27.
What is the best way to fix this issue?

Comment: add 0.005 and round down will have same behavior as rounding 1.265 up to 1.27.

Comment: @JeffJohnson Thanks, post it as an answer!

Comment: Fun fact: 1.265 can't be expressed as the sum of a finite number of powers of two, so it can't be represented exactly by a float. Most likely, it's actually stored as 1.2649999999999999023003738329862244427204132080078125, which of course rounds down to 1.26.

Comment: The best solution will involve using the `Decimal` module instead of binary arithmetic. You can't rely on the trailing `5` to really be the final decimal digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double rounding to overcome the inability of binary arithmetic to exactly represent a decimal value.

```
round(round(1.265, 3) + 0.0005, 2)
```